# Passing sql string variable into javascript function

Tags: php

I am trying to pass a string from a query into a javascript function.

An integer will pass into the function but string will not.

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='delete_game({$title});' 
class='btn'>Delete</a>";

<script type='text/javascript'>
function delete_game(title){
    var answer = confirm('Really?');
    if(answer){
        window.location = 'delete.php?id=' + title;
    }
}
</script>
```

I expected the javascript function to be executed, but instead nothing happens.

Comment: The string needs to be quoted inside of the function call. `delete_game(\"{$title}\")`

Comment: you shouldn't mix PHP + JS - it's bad practice. Inline js/css is also bad practice.

Comment: `instead nothing happens` I don't think is true. I would expect this to throw a console error.

Comment: @Peter I think that's the preferred - but don't think it's compulsory

Comment: @treyBake You're right. A google search told me it does the same thing.

Comment: @Peter ahh cool! I did a thing! xD I'd still prefer using `.href` though - feels better

Comment: is the value of `$title` a string or an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

I would change `window.location` to `window.location.href`
Change your echo to:

```
echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"delete_game('" . $title . "');\" class=\"btn\">Delete</a>";
```

Check if `$title` is set

```
var_dump($title);
```

If you'd like to make it a bit cleaner and are prepared to use jQuery:

```
<a href="#" class="btn delete" data-title="<?= $title ?>">Delete</a>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).on('click', '#delete', function () {
   var title = $(this).data('title');
   var answer = confirm('Really?');
    if (answer){
        window.location.href = 'delete.php?id=' + title;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this it works great.  One question though: why do we use a \ before the double quote?

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda actually `delete_game('$title')` accepts string value, you can make it as `onclick='delete_game('$title');` that would work fine too but when you use `"` this would break the string so you need to add `\"` so that It may not break the string

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda It's an escape character. Since you open the `echo with `"`, you cannot use it in your string without escaping it.

Comment: @RaviShankerGowda - If you don't want to care about escaping quotes (which makes the code a bit messier), I would recommend simply closing the PHP-tag, write your HTML and then open it again. Something like this: `?> <a href="#"...>...</a> <?php`. Then most IDE's can syntax highlight your HTML as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use ajax for this? As mentioned in comments mix PHP/JS isn't good.

In your HTML, you can do something like

> I'm assuming that you are using Blade.

```
<a href="#" onclick="return deleteGame({$title})">Delete Game</a>
```

Then in your javascript, you do this using jQuery:

```
function deleteGame(title){
    var answer = confirm('Really?');
    if(answer){
        $.ajax({
          url : "your-php-file.php",
          type : 'post',
          data : {
               title : title
          }
     })
     .done(function(msg){
          $("#result").html(msg);
     })
     .fail(function(error){
          console.log(error);
     }); 
    }
}
```

In your PHP you process receiving the data from post $_POST

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
```

You can understand better the Ajax function of jQuery [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).